# How to send the state values from one screen to another screen

Tags: react-native

I dont know how to send the value from one screen to another screen,

Here is my code

```
<TouchableOpacity 
style={{
        width:"100%",
        height:"200%",
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent:'center',
        backgroundColor:'green'
      }} 
onPress={() =>
this.props.navigation.navigate(
                                'cart',
                                { food  : this.state.item,
                                  amount    : this.state.ruppess 
                                } 
                            )

}>
<Text>Cart</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: i have the problem for transfer the data from next page. i don't know how can transfer the data. so please tell me have can transfer the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

to send the value

```
this.props.navigation.navigate(
                             "cart",{
                                     food: this.state.item,
                                     amount: this.state.ruppes
                                     }
                               );
```

to get the value on next screen

```
const food = this.props.navigation.getParam("food", "");
const amount = this.props.navigation.getParam("amount", "");
```

Comment: i have to used the same format for the code the value cannot transfer to the next page